# nested component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 3 level nested components. Html structure is like below. C and D's render node/element need to access state and custom function from Main, but C and D are inside B element. I am not sure if this is the best way to structure components. In addition, how do you pass down state and custom functions from Main to grandchildren C and D's render node/element?

```
<div id="Main">
    <div class="A"></div>

    <div class="B">
        <div class="C"></div>
        <div class="D"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My attempt:

```
var Main = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return (
            <div className="Main">
                <A/>
                <B /> 
            </div>
        );
    }
});


// Putting C, D into B, but C,D both need to access state from Main. 
var B = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return (
            <div className="B">
                <C />
                <D />
            </div>
        );
    }
});
var C =....;
var D =....;

React.render(<Main />, document.body)
```

Comment: I think this is normal, but don't forgot to append `className`s attributes.

Comment: How do you pass down Main's props to grandchild's render element?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure there is a direct way to access the state of child components. But you can use **ref**.

```
<Field ref="field1"/>
```

Then you can use

```
this.refs.field1.state
```

Your case:

```
var B = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return (
            <div>
                <C ref = "c1"/>
                <D ref = "d1"/>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

But this is not recommended as per this [link](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html#summary)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. My question is more about how I should structure my component parent and children relationship in better way in order to avoid situation like this. Since I am newb for react, not sure I am using the right structure here.

Comment: Acc. to me, your structure is right. For more ref check this https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html

Answer (score 0):

You may pass the state from Main as props of B

```
    var Main = React.createClass({

        getInitialState:function(){
            return {mainState:"Main state"}
        }
        render: function(){
            return (
                <div>
                   <A/>
                    <B mainState={this.state.mainState}/> 
                </div>
            );
        }

   });


    // Putting C, D into B, but C,D both need to access state from Main.



    var B = React.createClass({
     propTypes:{mainState:React.PropTypes.string}     
     render: function(){

          return (
                <div>
                    {this.props.mainState}// The state from main is received as propps in child component
                    <C mainState={this.props.mainState}/>// Now youcan access mainState a props of C
                    <D />
                </div>
            );
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you abhilash! so how do you pass Main's custom function to C's render node/element?

Comment: This is for a kind of validation. But does not throw  error. It will provide warning if the propTypes don't match. Also please put the tick button if the answer helps you.

Comment: You can also pass the custom function of main into the child component in the same way as states.
suppose you have a function 'handleClick' in the main and you may pass it to the child as props. <B handleClick={this.handleClick}/> and use it in side child component B in the way this.props.handleClick();

Comment: Thank for you answers. I think you misunderstood my question. I am looking for a way to pass props all the way down to C and D's 'RENDER' elements, so the render element can access Main's handleClick prop. Not passing to child component of Main, but passing to 'grandchild''s render nodes. For example, C has render ( <div ''I need handleClick here" ></div>)

Comment: had you tried spred(...) operator. you can pass all properties to child component with ...this.props. Also that level of passing props is not best practice

Comment: I agree that levels are very inconvenient for passing around props. that's why I asked if there was better structure in this case. I heard I might have to use flux to solve the problem

Comment: Yeah In flux you may keep the required data in the store. And get it with the Store.getSomething() methods . I strongly recommend to use flux architecture with react apps.